# angularjs ui-router: redirect vs multiple url for same state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I navigate first to my index page where the url is '/', I want to display the content of the state '/matches'. What you think is better?

I can use

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/matches');`
that works, but I know it's not a good solution.

So I have to choose between

1- redirecting `/` to `/matches` and I tried

`$urlRouterProvider.when('/','/matches');`
but it didn't work.

2- specify multiple paths `/` and `/matches` to the same state matches which I don't know how to do.

In ng-route I used to do it like this:

```
.when('/', {
    redirectTo : '/matches'
})
```

but I don't think it's good to combine ng-route with ui-router.

Comment: In your html file (header), you can add **<base href="/matches">**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect solution

```
 app.run(function($state){
  $state.go('/matches');
 });
```

Once the app runs, I call the state that I want to load using **$state.go** and I also kept the

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/matches');
```

in case the user tries to enter an invalid url (state), he will be redirected to the initial state.